# Formula to calculate a % IF value of cell X is greater than a value Y

Tags: worksheet-function

I am looking to create a formula to calculate tax payments. If cell x is greater than £11000, then calculate the excess at 20% of the excess figure. i.e. Cell A1 £12000, Cell B1 would thus be £12000-11000 = £1000 * 20% = £200. If cell A1 was £10000, value in B1 would be 0.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a basic IF statement here.

If you write it out you can see how it will work:

If the value in A1 is greater than 11000, calculate 20% of the difference. If not, display 0.

Excel IF statements work like this: `=IF(logical_test, value if true, value if false)`

If we take our written statement and translate it to the formula we get this:

`=IF(A1 > 11000, (A1-11000)*0.2, 0)`